# PHP - Simple for loop not working? No errors returned

Tags: php, for-loop

I'm currently having trouble printing some simple test statements within my for loop.

```
<?php
include('../connstr.inc');

$email=$_REQUEST["email"];
$datafile=$_REQUEST["datafile"];
$email_safe=preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/","_",$email);
$path="../uploaded_data";
$xml = simplexml_load_file("{$path}/{$email_safe}/{$datafile}.xml");

// Retreive data details for specified activity
$lapcount = $xml->Activities->Activity->Lap->count();
echo "LapCount: " . $lapcount;

$totalTime = array(); $distance = array(); $maxSpeed = array();
$calories = array(); $intensity = array(); $trigMethod = array();
echo 'Test1';
// Collect details for each lap
for($x = 0; $x < $lapCount; $x++) {
    echo 'Test2';

    // Find how many trackpoints exist for specified lap
    $trackPointCount = $xml->Activities->Activity->Lap[$x]->Track->Trackpoint->count();
    echo 'Test3';
    echo "<br /> Lap {$x} TrackP Count: " . $trackPointCount;
    echo 'Test4';
}
```

When I run it, only 'Test1' and the 'lapCount' gets printed. Anything within the for loop doesn't run. No errors are being returned either. $x will definitely be less then $lapCount as this is just 3. I fail to see the (most likely) stupid mistake I've made even after looking over it many times.

Comment: Your `$lapcount` must be 0 for the `for` loop to fail. Try to `var_dump($lapcount);` before the `for` loop and inspect the value.

Comment: Try to echo $lapcount

Comment: Think you just pointed me in the right direction. I'm using a capital 'C' in lapCount for my for loop, where as I'm declaring it as lapcount (lower case 'c').

Silly mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is this:

You declare lapcount as $lapcount, but try using it as $lapCount
(Notice the capitalization of the "C")

Ensure all uses of this variable are typed out exactly the same and everything will work

***EDIT:
Seems like you discovered this as I posted my answer***

Answer (score 0):

Initially you are using variable name `$lapcount` but in the last for loop you are using `$lapCount` that is the reason why you are not getting any value. Use $lapcount in the last for loop also.

```
for($x = 0; $x < $lapcount; $x++) {                // use $lapcount
    echo 'Test2';
    $trackPointCount = $xml->Activities->Activity->Lap[$x]->Track->Trackpoint->count();
    echo 'Test3';
    echo "<br /> Lap {$x} TrackP Count: " . $trackPointCount;
    echo 'Test4';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, the name of your var is $lapcount without 'C' lowercase:

```
// Retreive data details for specified activity
$lapcount = $xml->Activities->Activity->Lap->count();
echo "LapCount: " . $lapcount;
```

but here, you use 'C' uppercase, $lapCount:

```
for($x = 0; $x < $lapCount; $x++) {
```